# Active voice Vs Passive voice

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, grammaticality, passive-voice

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

> I got used to using the computer after I had admitted to the university.

Or,

> I got used to using the computer after I had **been** admitted to the university.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the passive voice.

> If someone **is admitted to** an organization or group, they are allowed
>   to join it:

1. I’ve been admitted! ([York University](https://futurestudents.yorku.ca/admitted))
2. He was admitted to the Académie Culinaire de France. ([the Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/admit))
3. I got used to using the computer after I had been admitted to the university.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's only the second *clause* of the second construction that has a passive construction. *I got used to* is an active construction in both sentences.

Second, it's not that you have to use a passive construction, it's simply that the first sentence is ungrammatical.

Either of the following is acceptable:

> I got used to using the computer after the university had admitted me.
>   I got used to using the computer after I had been admitted to the university.

The rephrased first sentence has a fully active construction and is grammatical.